# What does it mean for something to be $L^2(G)$ for compact G

Tags: group-theory, hilbert-spaces

For the particular example I'm interested in, I know a particular field F (maybe scalar, vector or tensorial) "lives in"  $L^2(SU(2))$. What exactly does that mean?

My intuition says that $$F\epsilon SU(2)$$   Or rather that the field consists of elements of $SU(2)$. Is that right?

**ELABORATION**

Based on the comments below, I think I need to elaborate on my question. First of all I am dealing strictly with compact groups. I was recently reading about the [Peter-Weyl theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter%E2%80%93Weyl_theorem), which for a simplified version of my case reads:

$$L^{2}(S^{3})=L^{2}(SU(2))$$ I understand that this ultimately is a generalization of the Fourier series expansion in that we can say that the $mth$ representation of $SU(2)$ is equal to the $mth$ harmonic in a series expansion of some scalar/vector/tensor on $S^3$. Thus we can say that:

$$F=\sum_{m}^{\infty}a_{m}SU(2)^{m}$$

Where we are denoting $SU(2)^m$ to be the $mth$ representation of $SU(2)$ and $a_m$ is the equivalent of the fourier coefficient. If $F$ is composed of a sum of irreducible representations of $SU(2)$ then isn't $F$ itself act as an element of $SU(2)$? Please excuse any poor notation/terminology, I'm quite new to Group theory, but definitely want to learn.

Apparently there is still some ambiguity in my question as per the comments below. In a paper describing [The harmonics on $S^3$](http://www.ccom.ucsd.edu/~lindblom/Publications/99_JMathPhys.S3Harmonics.pdf) they write that:

> the
>   expansion coefficients V
>   are simply the integral pro-
>   jections of the vector field onto the corresponding vector
>   harmonics

Comment: Look up $L^p$ spaces.

Comment: It means that $F$ is measurable with respect to the Haar measure on $SU(2)$ and the integral, with respect to Haar measure, of $|F|^2$ is finite.

Comment: @AndreasBlass      I Attempted to clarify the question

Comment: I'm afraid your clarification has made the question less clear. You seem to be multiplying representations, which you call $SU(2)^m$, by coefficients $a_m$ that don't seem to necessarily be integers, so it's not clear what that means. At first, I thought you might intend to multiply the matrices of the representations by these coefficients, but then your summation sign would mean adding matrices of different sizes, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: @AndreasBlass  take the U(1) case for example, the $a_m$ coefficients are strictly functions of m in this case, and we merely have the fourier coefficients of a standard series expansion of a periodic function on $R$. The coefficients are determined by the standard orthogonality relations. See examples in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter%E2%80%93Weyl_theorem. For the case of $S^3$ see http://www.ccom.ucsd.edu/~lindblom/Publications/99_JMathPhys.S3Harmonics.pdf

Comment: For $U(1)$, all the irreducible representations have dimension 1, so multiplying their matrices (of size $1\times1$) by scalars and adding makes sense. But the irreducible representations of $SU(2)$ have lots of different dimensions, so I still can't make any sense of what you've written.

Comment: @AndreasBlass  Please see link in above comment

Comment: I'm beginning to suspect that, although you wrote that $SU(2)^m$ is the $m$th representation, you actually want the entries of the matrices of the irreducible representations, not the representation themselves and not the matrices themselves. It remains unclear how you intend to index these by $m$. It is correct that a function in $L^2(SU(2))$ can be represented as a sum of such matrix entries multiplied by coefficients (that are themselves square-summable). But that doesn't seem to have anything to do with things like $F\in SU(2)$ that you wrote in the original question.

Comment: @AndreasBlass  Thank you, you are correct, having been trained in physics, I find myself attempting to learn a lot of new terminology and concepts usually glossed over. This in turn makes it difficult to express thoughts on the math forum. I'll be back after I brush up on this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compact groups such as $SU(2)$ have a unique normalized [Haar measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_measure) $\mu$ with total measure $1$. Haar measure on a compact group $G$ allows you to define the [Hilbert space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space) called [$L^2(G)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space) consisting of ([equivalence classes of](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation)) measurable square-integrable functions

$$f : G \to \mathbb{C}$$

where square-integrable means that the integral $\int |f|^2 \, d \mu$ converges, where $d \mu$ refers to [Lebesgue integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_integration) with respect to Haar measure, and the equivalence relation is that $f \sim g$ if $\int |f - g|^2 \, d \mu = 0$. So elements of $L^2(G)$ are (equivalence classes of) functions from $G$ to $\mathbb{C}$, not elements of $G$.

Due to the invariance of Haar measure, $G$ naturally acts on $L^2(G)$, making it a [linear representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_representation) of $G$, and one piece of the Peter-Weyl theorem says that this representation decomposes as a Hilbert space direct sum of $\dim V$ copies of every [irreducible representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_representation) $V$ of $G$.

The [representation theory of $SU(2)$ itself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_SU(2)) is extremely well-understood; it has exactly one irreducible representation $V_d$ of each dimension $d$, which is isomorphic to the representation of $SU(2)$ on homogeneous polynomials in $2$ complex variables of degree $d - 1$, and so the decomposition of an element $f \in L^2(SU(2))$ in terms of these irreducibles consists of, for each positive integer $d$, a collection of $d^2$ scalars describing the component of $f$ living in the sum of $d$ copies of $V_d$. This data can also be thought of as a collection of $d$ homogeneous polynomials in $2$ complex variables of degree $d - 1$.

Comment: @Qiaochu_Yuan   My understanding is there is also one irreducible representation for each m, I.e each harmonic. See https://www.physics.rutgers.edu/grad/618/lects/su2.pdf   Page 4 second paragraph.